# Darlington MOSFET Problem

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I want to turn a 5 kW motor on and off with an Arduino.
The motor is connected to a Siemens Sirius Soft starter, which should make the task relatively painless.

The soft starter has three input terminals:

- Plus is connected to 24V DC
- Switch/Signal: if set to 24V, then the motor will be running, if set to GND, then the motor stops.
- GND is connected to Ground

Because the Arduino runs on 9V, but the soft starter needs a 24V signal, I thought it would be a good idea to use a darlington transistor.

I used a TIP120 NPN Transistor ([datasheet here](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/150872-da-01-en-Transistor_TIP_120.pdf)) and I built the following:

[image: Schema]

Unfortunately, this does not work. I set the Pin11 to HIGH, but the emitter leg of the dalington still still has a GND potenial.

I suppose that the problem is caused by the fact that I am using the wrong type of darlington transistor. The TIP120 is not suitable for a source configuration.

A TIP125 would be a better choice.

Is this the reason my schematic does not work? Any other thoughts?

Comment: I can’t see any MOSFET anywhere. Why would you need a darlington? Smells XY problem. Is the Siemens thingamajingy actually a motor driver by any chance which accepts logic input, although at 24 V?

Comment: The mosfet is shown in the diagram as a 3d drawing.
I am not sure what you mean by logic input. But I know that if I supply 24V to the Switch/Signal terminal, the motor is swiched on.

Comment: Could you also explain what you mean by, "doesn't work"? How does it not work? Is it just idle? Did something generate magic smoke? EDIT: Also, you still have not demonstrated where the FET is. The TIP120 is **not** a FET, it's a BJT, NPN to be specific. And why would you want to replace an NPN with a PNP?

Comment: @user1691896 NPN transistor ≠ MOSFET – there is a fair difference between FETs and bipolar transistors (BJTs), the latter coming in NPN and PNP flavours. Do not call a BJT a MOSFET, it only confuses everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for your soft starter. I'm not sure if [this](https://www.industry.usa.siemens.com/automation/us/en/industrial-controls/products/solid-state-control/soft-starters/Documents/Manual_SIRIUS_softstarter_en_0110.pdf) is the one, but used it as a reference.

The Start/Run pin has to be driven to 24 VDC, and the schematic (barely) shows you are NOT driving the signal at all.

[image]

While I didn't look for the technical details of the Start pin on your starter, it seems likely it is internally pulled low, and pulling it high (to 24 VDC) will draw some defined current into the pin.

As other noted, you reference a TIP120 as a MOSFET ...it is not. In addition you are NOT driving the Start pin.

If you are in an industrial situation, then I would advise against taking non-isolated interfaces out to your wiring cabinet.
You should be using DIN or panel mount SSR to switch this circuit (if you really want to implement that kind of control), though it would be easier to simply use a relay.

My suggestion would be to use a Relay interface for the Arduino. They are cheap and do not require you to have detailed knowledge of the Start/Run pin configuration. 
 Something like this below is only $1-2:

[image]

Comment: THanks for pointing this out. Yes, I think I was too narrow-minded from the start. This is a better solution for my problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsBYUi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

you could use a n mosfet or npn transistor adding a resistor between 24V and collector/drain, base to arduino via resistor and source/emitter to ground.
Then, invert the output of the arduino because with this configuration:

1. the voltage on the switch/signal is 24 if the gate/base is low
2. the voltage on the switch/signal is 0 if the gate/base is high, because the MOSFET/transistor pulls it to ground.

take care that the resistor is high enough to limit the current when the base/gate is high

Comment: pure genius! Thanks a lot! I am sure this would work, but I will go with the relay solution anyway, because it is simpler.